# Minecraft compiling using JavaCompiler

Tags: java, string, compilation, rename, minecraft

My goal is to programmatically compile java code for a game called Minecraft. I am developing a modification that allows a user to write java files and compile them so that they can be installed into the game (The game is made in Java), I use the JavaCompiler class and it works fine, the problem is that when the game is de-compiled all the directories and names of everything change, but with JavaCompiler it doesn't as expected. I was wandering if there was a way to compile the java files and then edit the class with a chunk of code that will replace set strings with other strings that are also set, I have tried to have it changed in the java file and then compile, only the compile doesn't work as the imports and class names are invalid. Here is my current code:

```
package com.marko5049.TechRev.GUI;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticListener;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiButton;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiTextField;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

import com.marko5049.TechRev.TileEntityComputer;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler;

public class GuiProgramIDE extends GuiScreenMod
{
    private World world;
    private EntityPlayer entityplayer;
    private Minecraft mc;
    private final TileEntityComputer tile;
    private GuiTextField txtBox;
    private GuiTextField txtName;

    public GuiProgramIDE(World world1, EntityPlayer entityplayer1, Minecraft minecraft, TileEntityComputer compTile)
    {
        world = world1;
        entityplayer = entityplayer1;
        mc = minecraft;
        tile = compTile;
    }

    public void updateScreen()
    {
        this.txtBox.updateCursorCounter();
        this.txtName.updateCursorCounter();
    }

    public void initGui()
    {
        Keyboard.enableRepeatEvents(true);
        buttonList.clear();
        this.txtBox = new GuiTextField(this.fontRenderer, this.width / 2 - 150, 80, 300, 40);
        this.txtBox.setMaxStringLength(999999999);
        this.txtBox.setFocused(true);
        this.txtBox.setText("Text goes here!");
        this.txtName = new GuiTextField(this.fontRenderer, this.width / 2 - 100, 40, 200, 20);
        this.txtName.setMaxStringLength(32);
        this.txtName.setFocused(false);
        this.txtName.setText("Title goes here!");
        buttonList.add(new GuiButton(1, width / 2 - 105, height / 2 + 40, 100, 20, "Save"));
        buttonList.add(new GuiButton(2, width / 2 + 5, height / 2 + 40, 100, 20, "Open"));
        buttonList.add(new GuiButton(3, width / 2 - 105, height / 2 + 60, 210, 20, "Compile"));
    }

    public void onGuiClosed()
    {
        Keyboard.enableRepeatEvents(false);
    }

    protected void actionRPerformed(GuiButton guibutton)
    {

    }

    protected void actionPerformed(GuiButton guibutton)
    {
        if(guibutton.id == 1) {
            BufferedWriter write;
            String text = txtBox.getText();
            String title = txtName.getText();
            String name = txtName.getText() + ".java";
            String path = Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir.getParent().toString() + "/saves/" + world.getWorldInfo().getWorldName().toString() + "/TechRev/Compiler/";
            File destFolder = new File(path);
            if (!destFolder.exists())
            {
                destFolder.mkdir();
                if(!path.endsWith(name)) path += name;
                try {
                    write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
                    write.write(text);
                    write.close();
                    txtBox.setText(text);
                    txtName.setText(title);
                } catch(Exception e) {}
            } else {
                if(!path.endsWith(name)) path += name;
                try {
                    write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
                    write.write(text);
                    write.close();
                    txtBox.setText(text);
                    txtName.setText(title);
                } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
        if(guibutton.id == 2) {
            String title = txtName.getText();
            String name = title + ".java";
            String path = Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir.getParent().toString() + "/saves/" + world.getWorldInfo().getWorldName().toString() + "/TechRev/Compiler/";
            File file = new File(path + name);
            if(file.canRead()) {
                String FileTxt = "";
                if((path + name).endsWith(".java")) {
                    try {
                        Scanner read = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
                        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
                            FileTxt += read.nextLine();
                        }
                        read.close();
                    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}
                    txtBox.setText(FileTxt);
                    txtName.setText(title);
                }

            } else {
                System.out.print("Cannot Open File!");
            }
        }
        if(guibutton.id == 3) {
            String title = txtName.getText();
            String name = title + ".java";
            String src = Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir.getParent().toString() + "/saves/" + world.getWorldInfo().getWorldName().toString() + "/TechRev/Compiler/";
            File java = new File(src + name);
            File srcFolder = new File(src);
            if (!srcFolder.exists()) {
                srcFolder.mkdir();
                compile(src + name);
            } else {
                compile(src + name);
            }
        }
    }

    public void compile(String file) {
        String fileToCompile = file;
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
        if (compilationResult == 0) {
            System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
            entityplayer.addChatMessage("Compilation is successful");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Compilation failed");
            entityplayer.addChatMessage("Compilation failed");
        }
    }

    public boolean doesGuiPauseGame()
    {
            return true;
    }

    protected void keyTyped(char par1, int par2)
    {
        super.keyTyped(par1, par2);
        this.txtBox.textboxKeyTyped(par1, par2);
        this.txtName.textboxKeyTyped(par1, par2);
    }

    protected void mouseClicked(int par1, int par2, int par3)
    {
        super.mouseClicked(par1, par2, par3);
        this.txtName.mouseClicked(par1, par2, par3);
        this.txtBox.mouseClicked(par1, par2, par3);
    }

    public void drawScreen(int i, int j, float f)
    {
            drawDefaultBackground();
            int x = width / 3 - 128;
            int y = height / 3 - 128;
            try{
                    GL11.glPushMatrix();
                    GL11.glScalef(1.5F, 1.5F, 1.5F);
                    GL11.glColor4f(2.0F, 2.0F, 2.0F, 2.0F);
                    mc.renderEngine.bindTexture(new ResourceLocation("TechRev:App.png"));
                    drawTexturedModalRect(x, y, 0, 0, 256, 256);
                    GL11.glPopMatrix();
            }
            finally{
            }
            this.txtBox.drawTextBox();
            this.txtName.drawTextBox();
            super.drawScreen(i, j, f);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is a GUI that has a text box for editing, it saves the text in the directory and as .java files. Here is my test java file that was written in this GUI:

```
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod; import net.minecraft.src.ModLoader; import net.minecraft.item.Item; 
@Mod(modid = "TechRev", name = "Technological Revolution", version = "V0.1") 
public class TechRev { 
public static Item ChickenLegs = new Item(3000).setUnlocalizedName("chicken"); 
public TechRev() { init(); } 
public void init(){ ModLoader.addName(ChickenLegs, "Chicken Drumsticks");}}
```

As I said the JavaCompiler does what it is supposed to only I need it to rename directories and class names in the class file that is produced from the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to do something similar to what is done in the Bearded-Octo-Nemesis tool by immibis. BON allows you to de-obfuscate Minecraft mod archives using the configuration from an MCP directory that's been used to decompile Minecraft. The input is a production mod archive (which references the obfuscated Minecraft class/method/field names) and the path to your MCP directory.  The output is a mod archive that should be useable in a deobfuscated environment such as an MCP Eclipse workspace (you would put the deobfuscated mod archive in the mcp/jars/mods folder).

Here is a link to the BON source code; immibis uses a fairly permissive license, so you might be able to adapt his code to use the runtime deobfuscation data that is part of Forge.
https://github.com/immibis/bearded-octo-nemesis